# Are there any difference between Y and *Y, where Y is a list used as input argument?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I was using the torch.tensor.repeat()

```
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
period = x.size(1)
repeats = [1,2]
result = x.repeat(*repeats)
```

the result is

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]])
```

if I get result as follows

```
result = x.repeat(repeats)
```

the result is the same

```
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]])
```

It seems that `x.repeat(repeats)` and `x.repeat(*repeats)` work the same.

Does it mean that, for an input parameter, e.g, `Y`, I can use either `Y` or `*Y`

Comment: *args means that you can input any amount of args (inputs), instead of only one.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda. If `repeats` is a (`list` or `tuple`) of `ints`, then it is equivalent. But in general the rule appears to be:

- If the first argument is a `list` or `tuple`, take that as `repeats`. Ignore all other arguments.
- Otherwise, take the full `*args` as `repeats`

So if your `repeats` is something weird like `repeats=((1,2),(3,4))`, then `a.repeat(*repeats)` succeeds and is the same as `a.repeat(1, 2)==a.repeat((1, 2))` and `a.repeat(repeats)` fails.

Note: This is observational based on my own tests. The only official documentation is the defined type of the function, e.g. `repeat(torch.Size or int...)` which isn't perfectly clear with regards to semantics.

---

You can also get error messages like this:

```
TypeError: repeat(): argument 'repeats' (position 1) must be tuple of ints, not tuple
```

when you pass floats. In general error reporting could be better.